# Roaming Profiles using Samba on Linux Server

Tags: samba

I've configured an Ubuntu Server with Samba Active Directory Domain Controller. Everything works fine: I can add a Windows 7 client to my domain, I can share folders, DNS works properly... but when I try to create a roaming profile, it doesn't works. I have tried a lot of tutorials and webpages, but every time I want to login with a roaming profile, I get a Windows message saying that it was not possible to see the profile, so a temporary profile is used.

If I see the Windows Event Viewer, I get the error "could not find the specified resource".

My actual configuration includes:

- A created user in AD, with the profile path pointing to `\\server\profiles\username`.
- `Smb.conf` has a shared folder with the `path = \profiles` shared (I've tried a lot of options: `browsable`, `read only`...)
- The path `\profiles` is, of course, created and shared.
- In addition, I have used many times the Security tab, adding all users (domain users) to share this folder...

Could someone help me? I can attach some printscreen...

Comment: Solved. The problem was that I misunderstood something related with _winbind_ service.